# How to sort 3 parallel arrays

Tags: vb.net

I have a quick question about a project I am working on. I have three arrays and i have to sort them so that they all coincide with one another. I am able to do 2 but I cant figure out how to do 3 together. This is what I have so far:

```
array1() 
array2()
array3()

Array.Sort(array1,array2)
```

That will sort 2 of the arrays based off of the first one but I have to sort all of them based on the first one. Any info would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Quinn

Comment: Parallel arrays almost always means bits of data relating to a single actor is split up and held in different arrays.  Use a class to keep the info together.

Comment: To elaborate what @Plutonix said, (this may not necessarily be true in your case but) let's say that your `array1` holds peoples' names, `array2` ages and `array3` emails then you might want to create a `Class Person` with the properties `name`, `age` and `email`. After that, you'd be able to instantiate an array of persons and, in doing so, put yourself in a better position to tackle the sorting problem.